# Appended < IMG > tag with `src` from json file , is shown in html as a text and not displaying photos

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Appended image tag with src path from JSON file is displaying incorrectly . 
As seen in the console , to the `div` tag it is appended :

```
<div id="photoContainer" ></div>
"<img src=photos/43432424.jpg id=img1>" ( just string with "" ) 
"<img src=photos/43432424.jpg id=img1>" 
"<img src=photos/43432424.jpg id=img1>"
```

image can be seen here : https://jefrey12212445.imgur.com/all/

```
    <div id="photoContainer"></div>


`    <script>
     let photoContainer = $('#photoContainer');
     function renderImages(data) {
     data.forEach(function (item) {
        photoContainer.append(`<img id=${item.id} src=${item.location}>`);
        })

    };`

    `$.getJSON("/json/photos.json", function (data) {
    renderImages(data);
    });`
```

I want all the images from the JSON file be displayed as a gallery.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, you append a plain js string into the dom.
To create a new element in jquery, you can use e.g. `$("<div />")`.

For more information please have a look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_add.asp)

```js
let photoContainer = $('#photoContainer');

const renderImages = data =>
  data.forEach(item => {
    const newEle = $(`<img id=${item.id} src=${item.location} />`)
    photoContainer.append(newEle);
  })
  
//$.getJSON("/json/photos.json", renderImages);
// Fake API

const fakeGetImage = (_, callback) => callback([
  {
    id: "pic1",
    location: "https://picsum.photos/id/766/200/200"
  }
])

fakeGetImage("url", renderImages)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="photoContainer"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but your code appends plain js string "[object object]"

Comment: i did it like this :
`function renderImages(data) {
    data.forEach(function (item) {
        const newImage = document.createElement('img');
        newImage.setAttribute('src', item.location)
        imageContainer.append(newImage);
    })`

Comment: Hi Jefry, I added a fake API endpoint to the snippet and added the missing closing "/" for the image tag. Likely this was the problem.